# Volume charge density equation - dimensions not tallying

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Write an expression for the volume charge density $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ of a point charge $q$ at $\mathbf{r}'$ in terms of the Dirac delta function.

**My attempt:**

Let $\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}=\mathbf{R}$.

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{R^2}\hat{\mathbf R}$$

Taking the divergence of both sides,
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) & =\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\nabla\cdot \left(\frac{\hat{\mathbf{R}}}{R^2}\right)
\\
\implies\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r})}{\epsilon_0} & =\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} 4\pi\delta^3(\mathbf{R})
\\
\implies\rho(\mathbf{r}) & =q\delta^3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')
\tag{1}
\end{align}

However, the dimensions of the left hand side are 'charge per volume' whereas the dimensions of the right hand side are just 'charge' as $\delta^3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$ is dimensionless. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You should not need to derive it in this complicated way. The expression for $\rho$ is obvious if you understand delta functions. It represents a point charge at $\mathbf{r}’$ because the delta function is zero elsewhere. And the charge of that point charge is $q$ because that is the value of the integral of the charge density over space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathrm{all \; space}} \delta^{3}(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^{\prime}}) \, d^{3}\mathbf{r} \; = \; 1
\end{align}

The right hand side (i.e. 1) is dimensionless, and the differential element  $d^{3}\mathbf{r}$ has the dimension of volume. Therefore $\delta^{3}$ has the dimension of "per volume".

Comment: Alternatively, the relationship used by OP, $\nabla\cdot \left(\frac{\hat{\mathbf{R}}}{R^2}\right) = 4\pi \delta^3(\mathbf{R})$, also implies that $\delta^3(\mathbf{R})$ has inverse-volume dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

You got the right answer. The 3D delta function is *not* dimensionless; it has dimensions of inverse volume. Think about how its volume integral must give the dimensionless value 1.